# My approach to "background" processing in an (android) flutter app, not using another Isolate. Have I got this right?

Tags: flutter

Within a flutter app I need to do periodic processing of a resource (actually a sembast database) which is not multi-process safe but does support atomic transactions within a single process. In this context when I say process I mean Isolate (I think!).

I would also like to try and improve robustness by closing (to encourage flush to storage) and re-opening the database when the app lifecycle state allows.

I have implemented what I think should do this, and it seems to work for simples testing so I am soliciting criticism and suggestions to find out what I've missed, or misunderstood.

Attached a (summarised extract) of what I have at the moment.

```dart
class _SomethingState extends State<Something> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
// --- the backgroud processing stuff

  bool backgroundCanRun = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    backgroundCanRun = true;
    unawaited(runBackgroundPeriodically());
  }

  Future<void> runBackgroundPeriodically() async {
    while (backgroundCanRun) {

      doBackgroundWork();

      await Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 5));
    }
  }

// deal with app state changes

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        openSembastDatabase();
        backgroundCanRun = true;
        unawaited(runBackgroundPeriodically());
        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        backgroundCanRun = false;
        closeSembastDatabase();
        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow I feel like I must be re-inventing the wheel here but searches have so far not made me any the wiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. Indeed sembast is for single process/isolate only. Closing the database won't force flushing (data is always saved to disk as soon as possible). The main benefit I see in what you are doing is that it will definitely save memory space (as sembast hold everything in memory). However re-opening could take a lot of time if the database is big and you will need to handle this close/open state in your app code which could be a pain.

Comment: As far as robustness is concerned I was more thinking of the things which are probably out of reach of the application coed-specifically the dart runtime and the android filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

So, following Alex's hint, I plunged through the sembast code and I now understand that sembast appends lines to its file store with the sequence open/write/flush/close. This seems to be about all that can be done in userland to ensure that the data reaches the physical storage.

However, it's turtles all the way down and I do not know what the dart runtime does, nor the underlying android system. All I do know is that there is no point in me doing close/open on the sembast database in response to android lifecycle changes (unless it is to save memory, as Alex commented).